# Maven AetherClassNotFound

Tags: java, apache, maven, classnotfoundexception

**SOLVED** I solved the error by downgrading Maven to 3.0.5.

Original post:

I am quite new to Maven and want to use it with Android.

I try to go [this](https://sites.google.com/site/s70487s/android-research/maven) tutorial, but I am stuck at step 4, I get [this error](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound).

Running `mvn -version` returns

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 18:22:22+0300)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

There are quite few posts about it, and JIRA ticket for it, but I don't know how to fix as fast as possible.

Comment: The problem is based in the plugins which are not compatible with Maven 3.1.1

Comment: yes, that is why I downgraded it.